# (Temporarily) Preventing angular from updating view when object changes?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object that I'm sending over to a web server to store in the db. Between when I send it and when the operation completes I need to modify it slightly so the server can handle it.

In effect I have the following code:

```
$scope.o = {...};

$scope.send = function()
{
  $scope.sanitize($scope.o);
  SomeService.Save($scope.o).then( function() {
    $scope.unsanitize($scope.o);
  });
}
```

Sanitize just gets the object ready to send the server and unsanitize puts it back into a form that the view can handle more easily.

The issue I'm having is that between the call to sanitize and unsanitize, there's a few milliseconds of delay (or seconds, depending on how slow my network is at the time). During that time the view is updated and shows the changes that sanitize made. I don't want those changes showing up to the user while the server is doing its thing, though.

Is there a way of temporarily preventing angular from updating changes to a specific object?

I've created a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/29ze4exp/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Just don't modify the object that is bound to the view. Instead, use a copy.

```
var copy = angular.copy($scope.o);
$scope.sanitize(copy);
SomeService.Save(copy).then(function() {
```

Comment: Heh, that was the first thing I tried, but that doesn't work. I'm guessing the object is getting passed around by reference and angular is picking up changes to the copy in $scope.sanitize :(

Comment: @Alex, what you have is a confusion between a Model's object and a ViewModel's object. Model's object represents your back-end objects, and the ViewModel's object accommodates displaying in the View. You just need to copy from one to the other, and back.

Comment: @Alex you didn't do what my answer says. It works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/s3jpgv2L/ I also updated your `setTimeout` to Angular's `$timeout`, which triggers a digest cycle internally. That's irrelevant to your present issue. Just use `angular.copy` on the object like my answer says.

Comment: @m59 Ah, sorry. I missed the angular.copy statement the first time I read your comment. This works nicely, thank you!